# How to make two items in row in style components?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I map by array, and all I get is always an image which take 100% of width, I give inline style to smaller it, but there is a problem I cannot solve. I tried grid, I tried flex, I have problem with this.

```
        <FeaturesGalleryWrapper>
<Double>
            <AccordionSection>
        <Container>
    {AccordationDate.map((data, index)=> {
      return(
        <>
        <Wrap onClick={() => toggle(index)} key={index}>
          <h1 style={{fontSize: "16px"}}>{data.title}</h1>
        </Wrap>
        {clicked === index ? (
          <Dropdown>
            <p style={{fontSize: "14px"}}>{data.description}</p>
          </Dropdown>
        ) : null}
      </>
      )
    })} </Container>
  </AccordionSection> </Double><DoubleR style={{width: "120px"}}>
    {AccordationDate.map((data, index)=> {
      return(
        <>
           {clicked === index ? (
        <img src={data.imageUrl} style={{width: "100px", height: "200px" }}/>  ) : null}
        </>)})}</DoubleR>
          </FeaturesGalleryWrapper>
```

Herę is my style:

```
const FeaturesGalleryWrapper = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 15px;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 240px;
  align-content: flex-start; */
`;

const Double = styled.div`
 
  background-color: "red";
  
`;

const DoubleR = styled.div`
 
  float: right;
  
`;

const AccordionSection = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /* align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; */
  /* position: relative;
  height: 100vh; */
  background: #fff;
`;





const Container = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  box-shadow: 2px 10px 35px 1px rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.3);
`;

const Wrap = styled.div`
  background: #272727;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  h1 {
    padding: 2rem;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  span {
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
  }
`;

const Dropdown = styled.div`
  background: #1c1c1c;
  color: #00ffb9;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00ffb9;
  border-top: 1px solid #00ffb9;
  p {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
`;
```

anyone see simple solution to this state? As far as I Am concerned there is no difference to me if it would be in flex, or grid, or even table.